# Python query against firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP field

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

We have a Python (3.6) application and are using Firestore.

The field is called `timestamp_date` and it has the value of `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP`

We use this field for paginated query. One of the query that we have is

```
query_docs =  query_forward.start_at({
    u'timestamp_date' : input_date_variable
}).stream()
```

The value of input_date_variable is "2022-08-24T04:57:17.065000+00:00". How can we convert `input_date_variable` to a format of `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP` so the query works? Currently the query does not work.

Comment: Hi, have you checked my posted answer? Let me know if you have any questions or clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Epoch or UNIX time to query against the `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP`. By being said, you have to convert the value(if the value is a string) to `datetime` and then convert it to Epoch time. See code below:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

input_date_variable = '2022-08-24T04:57:17.065000+00:00'

d = datetime.strptime(input_date_variable, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
d = time.mktime(d.timetuple()) * 1000

query_forward = db.collection(u'collection')
query_docs =  query_forward.order_by(u'timestamp_date').start_at({
    u'timestamp_date' : d
}).stream()

for doc in query_docs:
  print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

Also, I would like to point out your query which will return an error. All fields in the cursor must come from fields set in `order_by()`.

For more information, you may check out this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#python).